# Emacs code browser "Store current window-sizes" doesn't actually save window dimensions

Tags: emacs, ide, cedet, emacs-ecb

I'm using emacs with CEDET+emacs code browser (ECB). For the most part, ECB works great. Hwoever, I'm trying to get the window sizes saved so I don't have to drag the panes around everytime I restart emacs.

When I choose from the menu: ECB / Layout administration / Store current window-sizes, something a few lines do indeed get added to my .emacs file. However, when I start up, the dimensions of the windows are not restored.

Any ideas on how to fix this?